# Is it any use going to the DevDays if you're not a programmer?

Tags: discussion, devdays

I'm still in doubt if it's worth going to the DevDays in Amsterdam, but since I'm not a programmer I have no idea if it's actually of any use.

Since I won't be able to "use" anything they would talk about.

So my question is: is it any use going to the DevDays if you're not a programmer?

Comment: So, why are you hanging around MSO? Try SuperUser.

Comment: @Pavium: I thought MSO is for the whole trilogy. And if you check Ivo's accounts page you'll see that the *is* on SuperUser.

Comment: Thank you fretje, I think I hang around SuperUser quite a bit ^^

Comment: Yes, I was being a little facetious, but thinking something like Ian Elliot, below. Didn't mean to offend ... sorry.

Comment: The information might not be geared towards you Ivo, but someone might want to meet the real Ivo. ;)

Comment: At least I would get to show off my stickers ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were deaf would you spend 20k on an amazing sound system?

DevDays seems to be catered towards the programming crowd. You may find interest in interacting and meeting other members of the SOFU sites, but as far as the talks themselves are concerned I'd say you would find it pretty boring.

If you're not a programmer, but are interested in *programming*, attend. If you're not a programmer, and have no interest in programming, you'll probably be in agony. If you really want to meet and talk with some other users attending, then that alone might be a good enough payoff.

Comment: Can you feel the bass of this amazing sound system?

Comment: No you cannot            !

Comment: Then you got ripped off if a deaf person can't feel the bass.

Answer (score 1):

If you're a manager of programmers (or want to become one), this might be useful for you to gain understanding of what programmer do and what technologies you might want to consider using.  Another reason to go would be if you're looking to recruit programmers to join your company.  However, if you're not a developer and don't want to become one and don't have some other motivation for going, I don't see why you would want to go just to go.